# Why switch for enum accepts implicit conversion to 0 but no for any other integer?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, switch-statement

There is an:

```
enum SomeEnum
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
}
```

Now compiler allows me to write:

```
SomeEnum x = SomeEnum.A;
switch(x)
{
    case 0: // <--- Considered SomeEnum.A
        break;
    case SomeEnum.B:
        break;
    case SomeEnum.C:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

`0` is considered `SomeItems.A`. But I can't write:

```
SomeEnum x = SomeEnum.A;
switch(x)
{
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1: // <--- Here is a compilation error.
        break;
    case SomeEnum.C:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Why only implicit conversion exists for `0`?

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14238286/414076

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [ECMA-334 (C# Language Specification)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

> **13.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions**
>
> > An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal
> >     0 to be converted to any enum-type.

[enum's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) default value is `0` and at compile time it is known that is why it is allowed in the switch statement. For value other than `0`, it can't be determine at compile time whether this value will exist in the enum or not.

[enum (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Assigning additional values new versions of enums, or changing the
>   values of the enum members in a new version, can cause problems for
>   dependant source code. It is often the case that **enum values are
>   used in switch statements, and if additional elements have been added
>   to the enum type, the test for default values can return true
>   unexpectedly.**

Comment: Have you found any explanation why it is so?

Comment: @yBee, I think its because enum's default value is `0` being an integer based value type.

Comment: Now I can imagine that if we create e.g. a `struct` or a `class` the fields are initialized. So if there is a field of enum type, its value is `0` even if there is no such item in that enum. So the field is in _cunfused_ state, but still valid. That's why we should always use `default` label in switch even if we have very simple and immutable enum.

Answer (score 4):

I would also add, that the syntax with `0` instead of the exact `enum` in the `switch` statement may become error prone. Consider the following code:

```
enum TestEnum
{
    NA = 0,
    A
}
```

and then

```
var e = TestEnum.NA;
switch(e)
{
    case 0:
        {
            break;
        }
    case TestEnum.A:
        {
            break;
        }
}
```

This compiles and works well. However if for some reason, `enum` declaration changes to

```
enum TestEnum
{
    NA = 1,
    A
}
```

everything will get broken.

Though in the majority of situations the default value for `enum` is `0` and for that reason this syntax may take place, I would use the exact `enum`.

Comment: The funny thing is, that even if I'll change `A` to `3` so that there is no `0` in `SomeEnum`, I can still write `SomeEnum x = 0` and catch `case 0:` label in switch.

Comment: @yBee Read the other answer, there is always a 0 value for an enum, it is the default value for the enum type defined in the language spec.

Comment: @yBee great notice...I even didn't realize that. As for me, I'd also avoid doing such things with `enums`

Comment: And also `SomeEnum x = 0; var name = Enum.GetName(typeof (SomeEnum), x);` The name is `null` as can be expected. So we've got `0` as valid value if it is defined in `SomeEnum` or `0` as `null` otherwise...