# C# enum - why does *implicit* casting from 0 work?

Tags: c#, enums, compiler-errors

Take this bit of code:

```
enum En {
    val1,
    val2,
}

void Main()
{
    En plop = 1;  //error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'En'
    En woop = 0;  //no error
}
```

Of course it fails when assigning `1` to an `enum`-type variable. (Slap an explicit cast and it'll work.)

My question is: why does it NOT fail when assigning 0 ?

Comment: **Duplicate** of  [Why switch for enum accepts implicit conversion to 0 but no for any other integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950750/why-switch-for-enum-accepts-implicit-conversion-to-0-but-no-for-any-other-intege) **and** [Compiler Value Type Resolution and Hardcoded “0” Integer Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224465/compiler-value-type-resolution-and-hardcoded-0-integer-values).

Comment: definite dupe, short answer, because it does.

Comment: by default, if the value of the first enumeration member is not set in the declaration, its value is zero. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Two really good answers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224465/compiler-value-type-resolution-and-hardcoded-0-integer-values/14238286#14238286

Comment: @DonBoitnott and Tim Schmelter - thanks for the links. Interesting reads.

Comment: I like the part of [Eric's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224465/compiler-value-type-resolution-and-hardcoded-0-integer-values/14238286#14238286) that says *"Second, the reason for allowing zeros to convert to any enum is to ensure that it is always possible to zero out a "flags" enum... The designers of C# 1.0 thought that it looked strange that you might have to say
`for (MyFlags f = (MyFlags)0; ...`"* That's the closest to a "why is the SPEC like this" answer I've seen yet.

Comment: Also related, and by Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one.aspx?PageIndex=1 (read the comments too!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's this way because that's what the spec says...

This is another reason why it's always a good idea to give all your enums an item with value 0, 'cos you're likely to get them with that value sometimes.

---

The appropriate section in the C# language spec 6.1.3:

> **6.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions**
>
> An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal 0 to be converted to any enum-type and to any nullable-type whose underlying type is an enum-type. In the latter case the conversion is evaluated by converting to the underlying enum-type and wrapping the result (§4.1.10).

As to *why* it's that way - well, I guess only someone on the language committee that decides these things would know.

In fact, we do have something like that if you look at rawling's comment to the original question.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Default initialization has nothing to do with the compiler allowing `myEnum = 0` in code. You can't assign `0` to a struct but they still get default initialized. You can't assign `0` to a `bool` but they still get default initialized.

Comment: @Rawling Good point, I'll admend

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can only implicitly use 0 is because 0 will always be a valid `enum` type where 1,2,3 or any other number might not necessarily be a valid type. For example try this

```
enum En {
val1=1,
val2=2,
}
```

0 is still a valid `enum` type because 0 is the default no matter what you do. Which means if you do not let one of your values be equal to 0 it will generate a 0 `enum` type for you.