# Using Default Parameter in Stored Procedure call

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetData]
@foo VARCHAR (20), @bar bit = 1
AS ...
```

This provides the correct result when called in SSMS.

```
EXEC dbo.usp_GetData @foo = 'Hellow World', @bar = 0
```

Although when calling within a C# application as per below

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@foo", foo)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bar", 0));
```

& is captured by the profiler as below.

```
exec dbo.usp_GetData @foo=N'Hello World',@bar=default
```

Does a parameter that overides the default have to be passed differently?

Comment: A bit is a boolean value what happens if you pass false instead of zero?

Comment: He is trying to pass 'false' for bit instead of the default. What happens if you try passing 'false' instead of '0'?

Comment: I want to provide a parameter & am in the above code but when the SQL is passed to the database it has `default` instead of `0` which is what I added for the `@bar` parameter @gunr2171

Comment: Let me try @jcwrequests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new SqlParameter("@bar", 0)` triggers the wrong overload - `string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType`. The value ends up being not set.

You want the one that sets the value, so it's ought to be `new SqlParameter("@bar", (object)0)`.

This is why [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) was introduced.

Comment: How does `0` map to `SqlDbType`?

Comment: @gunr2171 Nicely. It maps to `SqlDbType BigInt`, and it's a better match than to an `object` as far as the compiler concerned.

Comment: I don't think I said it correctly. How does `0`, an `int`, use the constructor form with a `SqlDbType`? Is there an implicit cast that allows this?

Comment: This worked fine but so did passing `false`. Is there any disadvantage using false as it just seems cleaner. @GSerg

Comment: @ojhawkins, your parameter is a `bit`, so providing the correct data type is always a good idea, instead of hoping sql will convert the integer correctly.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, there is an [implicit cast that allows this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16960428/11683).

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", 0)
```

This way you know you actually passing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Better and safe :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bar", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16, "bar");
```