# Why can I assign an int to an enum only when it is zero?

Tags: c#, enums, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

Try this minimal code:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo test;
    test = 0;
    test = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}

enum Foo { Bar, Baz }
```

The line `test = 1` will throw a compilation error, however the line `test = 0` is happily compiled!

> CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'UserQuery.Foo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Compiler version: Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.0.0.50618

Why can I only assign a value of zero? Shouldn't it be a missing cast error in either case?

Comment: The default for an enum   is 0(even if that is not a valid value for that enum).Other values must be casted: `test=(Foo)1;`

Comment: Because the language specification specifically calls out 0 as a special case that is allowed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever link?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950750/why-switch-for-enum-accepts-implicit-conversion-to-0-but-no-for-any-other-intege

Comment: @m0sa - [download the language spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029). You'll be wanting section 6.1.3 (Implicit enumeration conversions)

Comment: This behaviour is by design for two interesting reasons: 1) to fix a compiler bug, 2) to ensure that you can always zero out a "flags" enum. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224465/compiler-value-type-resolution-and-hardcoded-0-integer-values/14238286#14238286