# What does an implicit enumeration conversion convert?

Tags: c#

From C# 5.0 Specification

> **6.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions**
>
> An implicit enumeration conversion permits **the
>   decimal-integer-literal 0** to be converted to any enum-type and  to
>   any nullable-type whose underlying type is an enum-type. In the latter
>   case the conversion is evaluated by  converting to the underlying
>   enum-type and wrapping the result (§4.1.10).

Does "the decimal-integer-literal 0" mean the integer value 0?

If yes, why does an implicit enumeration conversion not permit other integer values such as 1, 2, 3, ... to be converted to any enum-type?

Thanks.

Comment: Eric's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14238286/15498) seems a good one

Comment: "Does "the decimal-integer-literal 0" mean the integer value 0?" it means a _literal zero value_, namely `0`. So not a _variable_ that could have a zero value. The other question is a duplicate.

Comment: @DStanley - the dupe you linked seems the opposite direction to what's asked here. I think they were asking why the zero conversion is limited to only 0.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fair enough.  I'll reopen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950750/why-switch-for-enum-accepts-implicit-conversion-to-0-but-no-for-any-other-intege?

Comment: From Eric's answer in the marked duplicate: _"the reason for allowing zeros to convert to any enum is to ensure that it is always possible to zero out a "flags" enum"_. In other words, ideally _no_ literal value would be implicitly convertible, but there were those on the design team who decided they wanted to be able to "zero-out" an enum type variable and allow that literal as a special case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it means the literal `0`. For example:

```
static void Main()
{
   Method(0);
}

static void Method(DayOfWeek dow)
{
  Console.WriteLine(dow);
}
```

should print `Sunday` to the console. If you change `0` into `1`, the program is illegal (compile-time error).

Only the (compile-time constant) zero has an *implicit* conversion to the enum type. For other values, you need an *explicit* cast instead, as in `Method((DayOfWeek)1);`.

*Edit:* This explains how the rules are. If you want to know *why* they chose those rules, I recommend the links in the comments (to your question above) by  Damien_The_Unbeliever and CodeCaster.

Comment: doesn't really answer the *why* of why 0 is dealt with specially. But I guess that's already dealt with by links provided.

Comment: I agree; I added a comment about that.