# Dynamically set INT value to Nullable enum property without explicit type cast

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, nullable

I have a method that populates a DataTable to simple DTO object. To simplify I'll use this example:

```
public enum Gender : int
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

public class Person
{
    //...
    public Gender? MyGender { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intValue = 2; // value from DB

    var o = new Person();
    var prop = o.GetType().GetProperty("MyGender");    
    prop.SetValue(o, intValue , null); // <- Exception
}
```

The above throws:

> Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[Test.Program+Gender]'.

If I declare `MyGender` as `Gender` (not Nullable) everything works fine.

It also works if I use an explicit Cast `prop.SetValue(o, (Gender)intValue, null);`

BUT, I don't want to (**and can't**) use the explicit cast: `(Gender)intValue` because I have no knowledge of the underlying "hard" type when I create the DTO object .

I was hoping for something like (**which dose not compile**):

```
var propType = prop.PropertyType;
prop.SetValue(o, (propType)intValue, null);
```

I also tried:

```
public static dynamic Cast(dynamic obj, Type castTo)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(obj, castTo);
}    
var propType = prop.PropertyType;
prop.SetValue(o, Cast(intValue, propType), null);
```

Which throws:

> Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to
>   'System.Nullable`1[[Test.Program+Gender...]

I am at dead end. what are my options?

*.NET Framework 4.6.2*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with. There's an explicit check to see whether the property being assigned to is nullable, but I don't think you can avoid that.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intValue = 2; // value from DB

    var o = new Person();
    var prop = o.GetType().GetProperty("MyGender");   

    // Check whether the property is a nullable. If it is, get the type of underling enum
    // Otherwise, get the type of the enum directly from the property
    var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
    // Convert the int to the enum type
    var convertedValue = Enum.ToObject(enumType, intValue);

    prop.SetValue(o, convertedValue , null);
}
```

Of course, bad things will happen if the property being assigned isn't an enum. `var convertedValue = enumType.IsEnum ? Enum.ToObject(enumType, intValue); : intValue;` would avoid that, if you needed it.

Answer (score 1):

A "creative" option to consider is:

```
var o = new Person();
o.MyGender = 0;
o.MyGender += intValue;
```

This looks odd, but it does work since the **constant** 0 has a built-in [implicit cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950815/34092) to enum (which other numbers do not).

So, you set it to 0, and then increment it to the **actual** number you are interested in. A key benefit here is you don't take the performance hit (and / or lack of type safety) of using reflection. *You may want to add a comment to the code as to why you are doing it as well. ;)*