# Why is Byte Promoted to Enum?

Tags: c#, enums

While using an external API that has several overloads that take different data types but no enums, I decided to create a handy method to give a bit more type-safety to enums and ended up with something like this:

```
namespace TestEnumPromotion
{
    enum Values
    {
        Value0,
        Value1,
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Prints int
            Overloaded(0);

            // Prints Values
            Overloaded(Values.Value0);

            // Does not compile! :-/
            Overloaded((byte) 0);

            // Prints int
            byte b = 0;
            Overloaded(b);
        }

        static void Overloaded(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("int");
        }

        static void Overloaded(Values i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Values");
        }
    }
}
```

But I was very surprised to see that the code does not compile because `Overloaded((byte) 0)`:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Overloaded(int)' and 'Program.Overloaded(Values)'

But `byte` cannot be automatically promoted to `Values`, that is `Values v = (byte)b` will not compile because:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to '`TestEnumPromotion.Values`'.

So the only possible overload should be int, right?

I thought that maybe enums were just syntactic sugar and that the compiler would generate methods that received int, but looking at the IL through ILDASM shows that a method was actually created that takes the enum.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Overloaded(valuetype TestEnumPromotion.Values i) cil managed
{
    // Code size       13 (0xd)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "Values"
    IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b:  nop
    IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Overloaded
```

What is happening?

Comment: you can declare enums based on other numeric types (for example `enum Values : long`), but the default is int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the consequence of a weird little rule in the language: literal `0` is implicitly convertible to any `enum`.

*UPDATE*: As per comments and linked sources, the compiler doesn't actually follow the spec. The compiler allows the implicit conversion of any zero *constant*, not just literal zero. You can read more about this issue [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one/).

This won't compile:

```
Values someValue = 1; //can not implicitly convert `int` to...
```

But this, funnily enough, will:

```
Values someValue = 0;
```

In your case, because `(byte)0` (constant zero) is implicitly convertible to `Values` and `int`, the compiler can't choose a best overload and fails unable to resolve the call. If you change your code to `(byte)1` or any other literal value, it will compile just fine.

Its worth mentioning that the reason why `Overloaded(0)` works is simply because the compiler finds an exact match; there is no need of an implicit cast, so `Overloaded(int i)` wins uncontested.

Quoting the c# 4.0 specs:

> 1.10 (...) The default value of any enum type is the integral value zero converted to the enum type. In cases where variables are automatically initialized to a default value, this is the value given to variables of enum types. **In order for the default value of an enum type to be easily available, the literal 0 implicitly converts to any enum type**.(...)

Comment: But `(byte) 0` is *not* "the literal `0`", so this is either incomplete or a compiler bug. (I seem to recall there is actual weirdness with constants cast to specific types that the compiler treats more flexibly than it should, but I can't recall the other question where I saw it. It could also be a consequence of the extremely convoluted rules C# has for overload resolution.)

Comment: [Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14238286/4137916)! Eric Lippert to the rescue, as usual. The standard is fibbing when it talks about "literal `0`", in fact any *constant* `0` is a candidate for conversion. Mix that with the overload resolution and Bob's your uncle.