# Exception "Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied." thrown even after supplying the parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying insert some entries in the database using a stored procedure which is called by a C# method as shown below:

```
public int addProfile(UserProfile NewUserPro)
{
    DataSet ds = ExecuteStoredProcedure("AddNewPro", new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@UserID", NewUserPro.UsrId),
                new SqlParameter("@Type", NewUserPro.Type),
                new SqlParameter("@Phone", NewUserPro.Phone),
                new SqlParameter("@Name", NewUserPro.Name),
                new SqlParameter("@FatherName", NewUserPro.FatherName),
                new SqlParameter("@GroupID", NewUserPro.GroupID),
                new SqlParameter("@IsPublic", 0)});
            return int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
}
```

`ExecuteStoredProcedure()` is a C# method created by me. It executes specified stored procedure and returns the output as a `DataSet`. This is the definition of that function:

```
public DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure(string ProcedureName, SqlParameter[] Parameters)
{
    try
    {
         using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("[dbo]." + ProcedureName))
         {
              com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              foreach (SqlParameter sp in Parameters)
                   com.Parameters.Add(sp);
              return SelectDataSet(com);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

As you can see in `addProfile()` method I am already providing `@IsPublic` parameter, but it's still throwing following exception:

> Procedure or function 'AddNewPro' expects parameter '@IsPublic',
>   which was not supplied.

`@IsPublic` parameter is an `int` parameter that saves value to `[IsPublic]` field which is an `int` field in a table with `null` allowed.

**UPDATE 1**

I am including the input parameters of the stored procedure. I think that will be enough? If you want I can include complete stored procedure but it's a lengthy code and due to some confidentiality reasons I have to cut some lines.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewPro]
    @UserID int,
    @Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Type int,
    @Phone VARCHAR(MAX),
    @GroupID int,
    @FatherName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @IsPublic int
AS
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok I found a little hint to the solution. When I put the breakpoint on the first line of `ExecuteStoredProcedure`, I found that its getting the value of `@IsPublic` as null. But I provided the value while adding the parameters. Why this is happening?

Comment: include your  `AddNewPro` stored procedure here please

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I'd suggest you have a bit of a think about your `try catch` in `ExecuteStoredProcedure`. Not only does it server no real purpose (it catches and throws all exceptions) but it doesn't rethrow them properly. You'd be better off removing it.

Comment: @maku I included the input parameter declaration part. Hope it will be enough?

Comment: try to use com.Parameters.AddRange(parameters) so no need for you to loop 
`And another thing, put a breakpoint in your code it must be the best way to find a solution to your problem.`

Comment: If you can, trace it via SQL Server Profile to see: what .net is passing to SQL, if the db is correct. Just to check: do you have multiple schema? Can be problem related to wrong chema issue?

Comment: @maku Ok I found a little hint to the solution. When I put the breakpoint on the first line of `ExecuteStoredProcedure`, I found that its getting the value of `@IsPublic` as `null`. But I provided the value while adding the parameters. Why this is happening?

Comment: Be careful to used zeroes, read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352260/why-does-the-sqlparameter-name-value-constructor-treat-0-as-null
this should be `new SqlParameter("@IsPublic", Convert.ToInt32(0));`

Comment: sqlparameter reads zero as an object

Comment: @maku wow that was some new concept I didn't knew about. I always used `AddWithValue()` it didn't required this conversion. May be its doing it inside. Thanks a lot it worked. Add this as your answer, I will mark it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlparameter reads zero as an object.

Be careful to used zeroes, read this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352260/why-does-the-sqlparameter-name-value-constructor-treat-0-as-null)

Must convert zero to integral type first .
Your code should look like this.

```
new SqlParameter("@IsPublic", Convert.ToInt32(0));
```

Comment: Golf clap! I guessed it was grabbing the wrong constructor overload, but you got there first.

Comment: @EdPlunkett what you mean?

Comment: I was complimenting you on answering correctly before I did.

Comment: No problem! I guessed that might be the case.