# Enum cast integer and number

Tags: c#, enums, casting, int

With a generic enum

```
enum MyEnum
    {
        a = 0,
        b = 1,
        c = 2
    }
```

If you have this two pieces of code

```
MyEnum myEnum = 0;
```

and

```
int a = 0;
MyEnum myEnum = a;  // ERROR, I need (MyEnum)a;
```

Why in the first one I can implicitly convert a number into an enum while in the second example I got an error because I need a cast?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `= 0` is handled explicitly by the compiler, you can't even write `MyEnum myEnum = 1;`.

Comment: Its the same as doing this  `MyEnum myEnum = default`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23762585/8873143) in combination with @LasseV.Karlsen's answer

Comment: This case is explicitly described in the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-enumeration-conversions): "An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal_integer_literal 0 to be converted to any enum_type and to any nullable_type whose underlying type is an enum_type."

Comment: While the duplicate is about `0.0` vs `1.0`, the answer there answers it perfectly.